# Why is the Mizbe'ach in Al Hamichya?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, bentching, mizbeach-altar

Why is the Mizbe'ach specifically mentioned in Me'en Shalosh blessing yet not particularly mentioned in benching which instead discusses the entirety of the Beis HaMikdash?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4402/14850

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the _Mizbe'ach_ isn't mentioned in the [Mishneh Torah's version of _Al ha-Michyah_](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2503.htm#13) (even in [printed editions](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58957&pgnum=276)), nor in [Siddur Rav Saadiah Gaon's version](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&pgnum=143).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[R. David HaCohen Scali](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99) suggests in [Kiryat Chana David vol. I, Orach Chaim 55](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1281&pgnum=132) that plant-based offerings on the altar included only *mezonot*-items and wine, but not bread.

Thus, specifically after eating *mezonot*-items and wine one mentions the altar in the blessing, but not after eating bread.

Comment: If you look inside in Kiryat Hanna David, he suggests that all menachot were pat haba bekisanin, where one would only recite birkat hamazon after eating a large amount

Comment: From https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.2.5 it sounds like חלות תודה ורקיקי נזיר are real bread, and there were identical menachos during the miluim https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Menachot.7.2 that actually went onto the mizbeach https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.29.23

Comment: @heshy What's your proof from Pesachim? Does anyone say you can't use *pat haba'ah bakisanin* for *matzah*?